# Help with understanding this proof in discrete mathematics?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility

This is the question and solution:

Q: Prove that for any integer $a$, $2a + 1$ and $4a^2$ + 1 are relatively prime.
A: Since $4a^2 + 1 = (2a − 1)(2a + 1) + 2$, **any common divisor of $2a + 1$ and $4a^2 + 1$
must be a divisor of $2$**. This means that $d=1$ or $d=2$. However, $2$ is not a common divisor as both $2a + 1$ and $4a^2 + 1$ are odd. Therefore, the greatest common divisor must be $1$.

Can someone explain how they knew that the common divisor of $2a + 1$ and $4a^2 + 1$ would be a divisor of $2$ (the bolded portion)? Is this some number theory that I just don't know? 
Also, this topic is $\gcd$ (greatest common divisor in discrete mathematics). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with some examples with actual numbers...

Is $10$ a divisor of $20\times23=460$? Yes. Note that $10\mid20$. This gives us a general rule: **If $d\mid a$, then $d\mid ab$.**

Is $10$ a divisor of $580-110=470$? Yes. Note that $10\mid570$ and $10\mid110$. This gives us a general rule: **If $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, then $d\mid a-b$.**

(P.S. Those are not *proofs*, but I hope they give you an idea for why these things are true.)

---

So, we're assuming that this number, $d$, is a common divisor of $2a+1$ and $4a^2+1$.

Note that $d$ is a divisor of $(2a+1)(2a-1)$, because it's a divisor of one of the factors (our first rule).

We have:
$$4a^2+1=(2a+1)(2a-1)+2$$
Subtracting $(2a+1)(2a-1)$ from both sides:
$$(4a^2+1)-(2a+1)(2a-1)=2$$
From our second rule, $d$ divides this also.

Comment: By the way, our second rule can be amended slightly: If $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, then $d\mid a\pm b$. In other words, $d\mid a+b$ _and_ $d\mid a-b$.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $d\mid n$ and $d\mid kn+b$; then there are integers $\ell$ and $m$ such that $n=d\ell$ and $kn+b=dm$. Substitute the first equation into the second to find that $k(d\ell)+b=dm$ and hence that $b=dm-dk\ell=d(m-k\ell)$, so that $d\mid b$. Now apply this with $n=2a+1$, $k=2a-1$, and $b=2$.

More generally, you can prove similarly that if $d$ divides any two of $a,b$, and $a+b$, it divides the third.